# Submit button of exposed form is not working when it is clicked 2nd time in drupal behaviors

Tags: javascript

I have created a search form using search API. After clicking on search button search results shows because of search API. Using drupal behaviors I have added a click event on search button, that when it is clicked the sub-menu's display:none; and clear search button - display:block;

The click event is not working on search button. It always shows results on every click but does not change the display property.

Can any one help me in this?

```
(function (Drupal, $) {

  Drupal.behaviors.icecreamBehaviors = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      $(document, context).once('icecreamBehaviors').each(function () {
        // e.stopPropagation();
        var searchBtn = $('#edit-submit-search-view');
        var inputFrm = $('#edit-search-api-fulltext')
        var leftSubMenu = $('#block-leftsubmenu');
        var subMenuList = $('#sub_Menu');
        var followUs = $('#block-followus-2');
        var clearSrch = $('#clear-search');
        var view_content = $('.view-content');


        searchBtn.prop("disabled", true);
        $('#clear-search').hide();

        inputFrm.on("change", function () {
          if ($('#edit-search-api-fulltext').val().length >= 2) {
            searchBtn.prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            searchBtn.prop("disabled", true);
          }
        });

        searchBtn.on('click', function () {
          leftSubMenu.css("display", "none");
          subMenuList.css("display", "none");
          followUs.css("display", "none");
          $('#clear-search').show();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#clear-search', function () {
          leftSubMenu.css("display", "block");
          subMenuList.css("display", "block");
          followUs.css("display", "block");
          $('.search-content > .view-content').hide();
          $('#clear-search').hide();
          $("input[name^='search_api_fulltext']").val('');
          $('.search-content > .view-header').hide();
          console.log("Clear Search Works!");
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(Drupal, jQuery);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal answers. The issue is likely because you are bypassing the Drupal JavaScript API. Maybe take a look at it: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: @Jaypan thank you.